# Как сделать такую рамку?

Tags: html, css

[image: Меню с задней дублирующейся рамкой]

даже нет идей с помощью чего это можно правильнее сделать

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На вид это 2 `bох-shadow` желтого цвета со смещением

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

span {
  font-family: Arial;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f5c506;
  padding:10px;
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: -3px -3px 0 0 #f5c50677, -6px -6px 0 0 #f5c50677;
}
```

```html
<span>ABOUT US SERVICES  ✉️CONTACT</span>
```

Comment: Да, точно, мне почему-то думалось, что можно только одну добавлять, спасибо большое